# Webpack output change v4 to v5

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-5

I'm in the process of upgrading a project that uses webpack from v4 to v5 and while it all compiles without error now (after some minimal tweaking) I noticed that the output format is quite different. Under v4 it had an outer structure like this:

```js
(function(modules) {
...
});
```

whereas now in v5 it has a structure like this:

```js
(() => {
...
})();
```

I *think* that is causing a problem for a particular way the output is being used in our project (specifically, the latter seems to be invoked, but the former doesn't seem to be).

Is there a setting that changed the default output in v5?

I tried looking at `output.iife` (no effect) and others in the docs, but didn't see something that looked right to me. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Update:

With @felixmosh's answer, I got part of the way there. The use of the function syntax instead of the lambda syntax is consistent now, but there's still the issue that it appears the v5 variant is self-executing and the v4 wasn't.

I added a repro over on GitHub based on the webpack getting started samples:
https://github.com/tlmii/webpack-v4-to-v5-example

Answer (score 1):

You can specify webpack's [target](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#string-1) to be `es`.

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  target: ['web', 'es5']
};
```

Comment: Thanks @felixmosh - that seems to have gotten me half way there. It now uses the function syntax instead of the lambda. But it still seems to be executing (it includes the final `()` that wasn't there in v4, just like the lambda variant did).

Comment: I updated my question with a link to a repo that exhibits this behavior (just the v4 getting started guide, tweaked slightly, before and after migration to v5).

Comment: Why the self invocation is an issue for you?

Comment: The way these bundles are being used, the "function" from each one is passed to an orchestrator before being executed (think of it as prepending `const myFunc = ` to the output of the bundle and then passing `myFunc` to another function). But it appears, since the v5 is executed, it returns `undefined` and the orchestrator detects that and throws an error. I just assumed there would be some way to keep the v4 style output.

Comment: What `orchestrator`?

Comment: It's custom, and rather basic. I can look into changing that but thought that getting v4 equivalent output from v5 would be the easier route. Perhaps not?

Comment: It probably can’t be changed, since it is related to the glue of modules.... btw check webpack’s module federation, perhaps it will replace your custom orchestrator